Postman signs for delivery himself. Any laws broken?
Suppose a Royal Mail worker knocks on the door to deliver a parcel which needs to be signed for. No one is home. He is supposed to leave a "Something for you" card and bring the parcel to the collection point. Or attempt again the next day.
Instead, the postman signs for the delivery himself, trying to make it appear like signed by the recipient, and leaves the parcel at the door.
This conduct would of course break Royal Mail's internal policies and procedures, but would it also break any laws?
If it matters, let's assume the parcel was later found by the recipient safe and sound.

Forgery

A person is guilty of forgery if he makes a false instrument, with the intention that he or another shall use it to induce somebody to accept it as genuine, and by reason of so accepting it to do or not to do some act to his own or any other person’s prejudice.

s1 of the Forgery and Counterfeiting Act 1981.
It is not a strict liability offence so each of the elements must be proved beyond reasonable doubt. The mail person’s intention must be inferred from their actions since no one but them has access to the inside of their head.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
